# How to get Microsoft 365 Planner 'All Plans for all users' using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have got a requirement to list **all Plans for all users** along with their respective buckets **within the organization**.

I tried OAuth authorization services (AAD > App registrations) to access the planner APIs/resources using the Graph API Endpoint however I am getting access denied - It is important to mention here that the app has got all the privileges.

Does Microsoft allow to read all Planners data? provided the account has all the required permissions - if so then what am I missing here?

```
public static string GetAccessToken_Delegate()
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Globals.AuthorityUrl, true);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Globals.GraphResourceUrl, Globals.AppId, new Uri(Globals.RedirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string graphToken)
    {
        try
        {
            DelegateAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
            return new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async static Task<List<PlansData>> GetPlans()
    {
        List<PlansData> plansData = new List<PlansData>();
        try
        {
            String accessToken = GetAccessToken_Delegate();
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphClient(accessToken);
            if (graphClient != null)
            {
                message += string.Format("GraphClient Base Url: {0}", graphClient.BaseUrl) + Environment.NewLine;

                plansData = await GetGroup(graphClient, plansData);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("GraphServiceClient is null");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return plansData;
    }

    public async static Task<List<PlansData>> GetGroup(GraphServiceClient graphClient, List<PlansData> plansData)
    {
        try
        {
            IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage groupCollection = await graphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();

            if (groupCollection?.Count > 0)
            {
                message += string.Format("Group Count: {0}", groupCollection.Count) + Environment.NewLine;

                foreach (Microsoft.Graph.Group group in groupCollection)
                {
                    if (group is Microsoft.Graph.Group)
                    {
                        if (group != null && group.GroupTypes != null && group.GroupTypes.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            plansData = await GetPlanData(graphClient, plansData, group);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        return plansData;
    }

    public async static Task<List<PlansData>> GetPlanData(GraphServiceClient graphClient, List<PlansData> plansData, Microsoft.Graph.Group group)
    {
        try
        {
            //https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/a047a2b3-3687-4464-bbdb-084f675c7528/planner/plans

            //Get Plans Information based on the group id
            IPlannerGroupPlansCollectionPage plansCollection = await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Planner.Plans.Request().GetAsync();
            if (plansCollection?.Count > 0)
            {
                message += string.Format("Plans Count: {0}", plansCollection.Count) + Environment.NewLine;

                foreach (PlannerPlan record in plansCollection)
                {
                    List<Bucket> bucketsList = await GetBuckets(graphClient, record.Id);
                    Groups groupData = new Groups(group.Id, group.DisplayName);
                    string siteUrl = string.Format("https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/teams/{0}/", group.MailNickname);
                    plansData.Add(new PlansData(record.Id, record.Title, siteUrl, groupData, bucketsList));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        return plansData;
    }

    public async static Task<List<Bucket>> GetBuckets(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string planId)
    {
        List<Bucket> bucketsList = new List<Bucket>();

        try
        {
            //https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/CONGZUWfGUu4msTgNP66e2UAAySi/buckets

            //Get Plans Information based on the group id
            IPlannerPlanBucketsCollectionPage bucketCollection = await graphClient.Planner.Plans[planId].Buckets.Request().GetAsync();
            if (bucketCollection?.Count > 0)
            {
                message += string.Format("Buckets Count: {0}", bucketCollection.Count) + Environment.NewLine;

                foreach (PlannerBucket bucket in bucketCollection)
                {
                    Bucket b = new Bucket(bucket.Id, bucket.Name);
                    bucketsList.Add(b);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEvents.WriteException(ex);
        }
        return bucketsList;
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add details on what you mean by "the account has all the required permissions"? Please also include code demonstrating how you are obtaining an access token to call Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret: updated the code snippet - have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use application permissions to read the data.

Outdated Reply:

> Planner does not support Application permissions yet. Exporting all
> plan data is possible with a non-graph API and requires a delegated
> access token for tenant admin. We're working on the documentation for
> this and making it available from graph as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate please on the following: 
1. Exporting all plan data is possible with a non-graph API => non-graph API, means Dot Net Code? Rest Api? |
2. requires a delegated access token for tenant admin. => in my code above, I am taking through a delegated access token (Group.Read.All & Group.ReadWrite.All) - using these permissions, I am getting Access Denied - what all permissions do the app need more? |
3. We're working on the documentation for this and making it available from graph as well. => any tentative date?

Thanks

Comment: It is a separate rest API. Graph is built on top of this API, so the shape is very similar. 
Delegated access token is a token where the user signs in into the app, and the token contain both the user's information and the app's information. The user needs to be the tenant admin in this case. We currently do not have a timeline. 

However, you can solve your problem with a workaround using the same delegated access token for the tenant admin (on Graph API):
Loop through the groups
For each group, add the admin as a member if needed
Read Planner data
Remove admin from members, if added